# Intel-style inline assembly in gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, intel

I am trying to compile an old C++ software project in Code::Blocks using the gcc compiler, and after fixing a few other issues, I've hit a wall: the project has a file with Intel-style inline ASM written as

```
_asm {
  code here
}
```

and the compiler refuses to compile it with "error: '_asm' was not declared in this scope".

I've spent a while Googling around looking for solutions, but the only ones I can find are to add `-masm=intel` to the build options (which I've tried and can't get to work), or to convert the code to `asm ("code here");` (which isn't feasible because of the sheer amount of ASM). Does anyone know how I can get gcc to compile this code as-is, or should I give up and use a different compiler?

Comment: How about generating a macro, and then using a script to replace the _asm lines with the macro. Then you get better compiler independence.

Comment: A macro would be an idea, though I've never used one before so I'd have to figure that out too (despite what my question made it sound, I'm actually pretty much a complete noob with this stuff =/ ). In addition, asm routines are linked together with labels or something (`_asm {\n code here\n } L01: __asm ...`), and I'm not sure how to handle that.

Comment: The code will not compile as-is, you will need to change it to get it to compile with gcc (or use MSVC instead).

Comment: Recently Clang added support for MS-style inline assembly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCC uses a [very different syntax](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html) for inline assembler, so you won't be able to handle it with trivial changes. I see the following options:

1. Rewrite everything in GCC syntax or as C code
2. Make some script to translate to GCC syntax (non-trivial task)
3. Compile the code with whatever compiler it was written for (MSVC?)

Comment: Option 2 is insanely optimistic. Forget it!

Comment: Option 1 is not an option; the file in question consists entirely of asm and weighs in at 83 kb, with several hundred functions. It's looking like I'll just have to switch compilers, then.

Comment: Someone actually did Option 2, it's called `intel2gas`, I've used it in similar porting efforts.

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't get gcc to compile the code 'as is'. If you need to compile this thing using gcc, you have to rewrite the code, in C++ or gcc-compatible asm. If there really is a lot of assembly code -- say, 200 instructions or more -- it might be worthwhile learning the gcc assembler syntax; if not, code it in C++.

Comment: See my comment on Igor's answer; rewriting isn't an option in this case because there are thousands of instructions (200 would be a pretty nice step down!).